# How can a Facebook app get a box on a user's profile?

Tags: facebook

[image: Soundcloud and Tumblr on a user's FB profile, visible to their friends]

I saw Soundcloud and Tumblr on a user's FB profile, visible to their friends (me).  Facebook developers: how is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called [Collections](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/collections/) which can contain app and activity-driven sections. Quoting from Facebook documentation

> These sections let people express to the world the things that they care about the places they've been or the things they've done. Facebook provides default sections that people can optionally populate from common options (actions) generated by apps. As an example, Facebook provides a Books section, which is populated by the common actions like books.read and books.wants_to_read.

If you've created custom actions and objects you can create custom collections for your app. Those collections will be available in your app's section. These sections aren't shown on the timeline by default, but you can [ask them to add your section to their Timeline](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/collections/#customprompt).

Comment: Anvesh, is that mean that I can't create custom section via Facebook app in personal profile timeline? This is my original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40532698/how-to-create-facebook-app-that-has-own-custom-section-tab-badge-block-box-in

Comment: @AngelTsvetkov I guess what you want to achieve is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-actions

Comment: Anvesh, not exactly, In example I want to send picture from my Facebook App to my Facebook App's section (collections) on the wall like Tumblr in picture above.