# How can a Facebook app get a box on the user's profile?

Tags: facebook

I'm interested that how can my Facebook app get a custom box on the user's profile.

I've found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479310/how-can-a-facebook-app-get-a-box-on-a-users-profile) (with answer), but that's more than a year old, and the linked docs do not exists anymore. Any docs, or tutorial I found is more than a year old, and links to unreachable docs.

So, how can my app create boxes like theese:

[image: Example]

Comment: That is Open Graph Collections that have been deprecated. So no you can not use them

Comment: Thanks! I thought, that the Collections had been deprecated. Any other solution, to create something like this?

Comment: No, there is no other way to do it.

Comment: I am disappointed. :-( Thanks for the help! (If you post this as an answer, I'll accept that!)

Comment: @WizKid Can you tell me, than how Shazam, or Foursqare got their custom Section on my Profile page? See: http://snag.gy/LLuHQ.jpg

Comment: Yes they are using Collections. That are deprecated and can not be used anymore